# Use ref to focus but set ref with conditioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Editor
    {...other}
    {this.props.isFocus && ref={input => input && input.focus()} }
/>
```

Above code will have error, how to focus children component according to a flag passed from the parent?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that kind of logic to set a prop to a component. You could instead do one of the following:

```
<Editor
    {...other}
    ref={this.props.isFocus ? (input => input && input.focus()) : null}
/>
```

or

```
{this.props.isFocus ? <Editor
    {...other}
    ref={input => input && input.focus()}
  />
: <Editor {...other} />}
```

---

That being said, I don't think you're using `ref` properly. I don't think there is any valid reason to have a `ref` only under certain conditions; it should be a static prop regardless of your application logic.

Otherwise you are most likely using `ref` incorrectly, but why or how is hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.